# Relative clauses and What it modifies

Tags: relative-clauses

I saw this sentence on a book

> Health can be defined as “[a] state of being associated with freedom from disease and illness that also includes a positive component (wellness) that is associated with a quality of life and positive well-being"

Does the clause "That also includes a positive component that is associated with a quality of life and positive well-being." modify "freedom" or it modifies "illness"?

I think it modifies freedom, but I was taught that relative clause always modify the noun before it, so it really confuses me. Can there be any exceptions?

Comment: By the way, we say *in* a book in speaking of the book's contents.

Comment: The relative clause logically modifies "component". "Freedom" is too far away, and it makes sense that there is some positive component that is associated with a quality of life ..." Relative clauses don't always modify the nearest noun: compare "He is **one** of her colleagues [**who** is always ready to criticise her]". Here, the nearest noun is the plural "colleagues", but in fact the relative clause modifies "one".

Comment: @BillJ thanks for the answer, the relative clause tip is really helpful. But my question concerns about the first 'that' , " that also includes..."

Comment: Yes, of course. It refers to "state of being".

Comment: @BillJ What about this sentence? "But his digressive narrative-which sometimes makes use of self-amused listicles-seems suspiciously influenced by styles that are popular on the digital platforms he inveighs against."

Comment: Is it "styles" that he inveighs against or "digital platforms" that he inveighs against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noun which precedes the second relative clause is *component* (glossed as *wellness*).

The first relative clause (*that also includes...*) actually refers to *state of being*. Identifying this is tricky, because the author is struggling to express a fairly complex proposition in the form of a traditional dictionary definition, and not succeeding very well. The clues are the parallel *associated*s and the implicit parallel in the term *positive*—this contrasts with the 'negative' *freedom* (negative because it denotes an absence).

Parse it this way:

```
                 associated with freedom from disease and illness [IMPLICITLY 'NEGATIVE']
a state of being
                 that also includes a positive component (wellness)
                                    that is associated with a quality of life and positive well-being
```

Or paraphrase it this way:

> ... a state of being which embraces both the absence of disease and illness and the presence of positive well-being and quality of life.

ADDED:
The general principle, that a relative clause modifies the immediately preceding nominal, is always subject to the qualification that the modification must be syntactically correct and semantically meaningfully. For instance, a relative with a plural reference can only modify a plural nominal.

In practise, it's always easiest to parse if you set your relative immediately after the nominal it modifies, but in very complicated situations this may not be convenient or even intelligible.

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer, but I realized I asked the wrong sentence earlier and has been edited. The question should be

Comment: Does the clause "That also includes a positive component that is associated with a quality of life and positive well-being" modify "freedom" or it modifies "illness"?

Comment: @黃冠霖 Neither -- it modifies "state of being", defining a 'positive component' which contrasts with the preceding 'negative' component (negative because it describes an 'absence' of disease and illness).

Comment: Thank you! That makes it understandable. Then "which is " can optionally precede "associated with...... and illness", is this correct?

Comment: @黃冠霖 Yes, though that doesn't solve all the problems with the sentence! See my suggested paraphrase.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much for the answer and the paraphrase, now I understand the structure and the meaning :)

Comment: Sorry, last question, what about my second question. I was taught that clauses modify the noun which precedes it. Is this rule always correct? Cause according to the original sentence, the clause is modifying a noun which is quite far away from it.

Comment: @黃冠霖 See my addition.